# making a modal JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jinternalframe

I need to get lots of data (file select , text, date ,...) from user in a MDI JFrame.
I need the input form that is a `JInternalFrame` be modal.
How Can I make a `JInternalFrame` modal?

Comment: Why don't you use a `JDialog` for that? `JInternalFrame` cannot be modal unless you extend it

Comment: @GETah: `JDialog` don't work  as Internal dialog! it comes out of MDI Frame! Can I capture it in the `JDesktopPane`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, see my answer below for an interesting link to a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience, I have never managed to make `JInternalFrame` modal and don't think that is possible out of the box.

See [this](http://webbyit.blogspot.no/2011/03/managing-jinternalframes-within.html) great article on an extension to `JInternalFrame` to make them modal (*thanks to Steve Webb*).

Comment: @trashgod Seriously!!? Is that from you? I have always watched your site for new tricks and tips on Java :). Hat's off, the application is really well made!

Comment: Edited my answer, you are on it now :)

Comment: @trashgod :) I already saw some of your controls that't why I had no doubt ;)