# Jinternalframe - only that frame is focusable

Tags: java, netbeans, focus, jframe, jinternalframe

So, in my little program on netbeans I open a JinternalFrame in a JDesktopPane (wich is contained in a JFrame), but I really wish to find out how to focus only the JinternalFrame while it's open. Let me explain to you better, when the JinternalFrame is open, I don't want my JFrame behind to be clickable or focusable until my JInternalFrame is closed.

I open my JinternalFrame like this:

```
    JinternalFrame cf = new JinternalFrame();
    Desktop.add(cf);
    cf.setVisible(true);
```

I know that changing my JinternalFrame with a Jdialog would be an option, but i really hope that there is another way to do it.
Anyone got some ideas?

Comment: I think [this helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177003/making-a-modal-jinternalframe)