# Show InternalFrame in front of Glasspane

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, glasspane

I want an InternalFrame to be shown in front of a GlassPane.
In my program the user should be able to click on FILE -> Settings and an InternalFrame should be displayed. Everything in the background should be covered with a GlassPane.
Does somebody have an idea?

```
m21.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Settings settings = new Settings();

        //get the InternalFrame
        settings.getFrame().setBounds(100,100,getWidth()-200, getHeight()-200);
        settings.getFrame().toFront();

        setGlassPane(new Glass());
        getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

        //get the InternalFrame
        getLayeredPane().add(settings.getFrame(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getLayeredPane().moveToFront(settings.getFrame());

        repaint();
    }
});
```

[image: GlassPane]

Comment: Reading [How to use Rootpanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) this does not seem possible. A `GlassPane` is added on top of all other components including a `JLayeredPane`. Perhaps a `JDialog` would work

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I assume that your class `Glass` extends `JPanel`. You can add `JComponent`s to it just like you can for any `JPanel`. Why does it have to be a `JInternalFrame`? I think a modal `JDialog` is also a possibility. Maybe even a `JOptionPane`. Or even a [modal internal frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177003/making-a-modal-jinternalframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the [glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) is to be in front of everything else:

[image: glasspane]

However, you can set any component as glass pane. My suggestion would be that you  push the content of your settings frame as glass pane.